# How do I get rid of target devices to install on the Play store?

Tags: google-play-store, browser

Each time I visit the Play Store website via the PC and want to install an app, I get not just my device (Pixel 2), but an emulator that I once used :

[image]

I tried to go to the settings on the Play Store website ([here](https://play.google.com/settings)), and saw my Android TV there (twice for some reason) and a device I used for just a day or so (some LG device), but not the emulator:

[image]

How come I can't delete items here? How come the emulator isn't here?
So I went to my Google account website, and found a place there (here) to show all my connected devices, and noticed the emulator there, together with my Android TV (again twice) and some PCs that I use:

[image]

I tried to sign out of the useless ones (and the emulator), went back to the Play Store app, and I still can see the emulator being offered to me.

I don't get why I still get offered to use it, and it's not even recently used, so why is it the first I'm being offered to install to?
Really annoying. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: AFAIK only devices appear that have downloaded at least one app using PlayStore app on the device.

Comment: @Robert So? How can I remove it? It's really annoying. I can't ever install there anymore. It's an emulator, and it was reset completely already...

Comment: As far as I know you can't remove devices that no longer exist. They will automatically be removed by Google after some months.

Comment: @Robert OK suggested here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143729916